# Setting folder permission so it isn't deletable, but everything else is allowed

Tags: permissions, directory

I want to set permissions to a folder such that, when I'm normally logged in (meaning not as root), this folder **isn't** deletable, but I can still change the name of this folder and move in around in my system ?

IS this possible and if yes, how to set the permission ? I already tried different combinations for the permissions but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Also (side question), if some folder hast some permission set and I copy this folder, along with its contents (assuming I am allowed to read it) to a memory, are these permission preserved ? I suppose not, since under Windows I could delete the folder on the stick, even if under Ubuntu it isn't allowed to delete it...

Comment: It could be a stick bit. please show the output of `ls -lid /path-to-folder` (this directory permission)

Comment: @maythux Sorry for the late response. This is what it shows, as I have configured it now (every permission is "Acces only" for folders and "-" for files): 1319179 dr-xr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 2012-10-07 13:01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the answer to your question is that **this is not possible**, at least not in the way you want it to work. However, let us dive into that problem and consider several issues.

First of all, notice that if you have at least one file in the directory, it will not be possible to remove it from the command line using the `rmdir` command. So that's something already.

Secondly, the permissions to *rename* the folder are not given by the permissions of the folder itself, but of the folders that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Folder then click the properties 
Next click permission tab 
Here now you edit tour permission for the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could give ownership of a directory and it's contents to another user (e.g. in a terminal `sudo chown root:root mydir`), you can create files in such a directory completely owned by this other user (which makes it a bit more difficult to delete), but under nautilus you can still press the DELETE-key on a directory which simply moves it to Trash.

Concerning the copy question: permissions should be copied as well, but ownership however will not be copied.